# Magento - Change Skin and Package in DataBase

Tags: sql, database, magento, package, skin

I am currently creating a full install script for Magento and Node.js/Grunt
I'd like to skip installation steps.
One of my goals is to configure skin and package directly without accessing the admin (I know how i can do that in the magento admin)
So, someone know which table(s) contain package and skin name ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is in **core_config_data** just check it out with your **scope**  and **scope_id** with if u have multistore.

below are the **path** column which you can find in table

**design/theme/skin**

**design/theme/template**

**design/theme/layout**

hopw this will sure help you

Comment: what about **design/package/name** and **design/theme/default** ?

Answer (score 1):

you can find on table core_config_data, 
with path:

```
- design/theme/locale
- design/theme/template
- design/theme/skin
- design/theme/layout
```

Answer (score 0):

On Magento 2, the `core_config_data` table key appears to be:

`design/theme/theme_id`

You need to look up the theme ID from the `theme` table.

To set it globally, use `scope=default` and `scope_id=0` - these settings will be different if you want to set the theme on a specific store or view.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to update the theme via the database, in Magento2, the theme settings are store in the `design_config_grid_flat` database table. The `theme_theme_id` field references the `theme_id` in the `theme` database table.